# Are there any established standard practices for video on the web while supporting mobile?

Tags: video, mobile

Seeing as how Flash Video isn't well supported in the mobile world, are there any best practices for embedding video on a website ensuring that it can accessed by as many devices as possible? 
(short of creating a native app like the ted / you tube apps)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are no standarts, but there are formats specifically made for mobile. Youtube has 3GP video on ALL videos, so it's a good bet. (Yes, all videos on Youtube have a 3GP version).

It's not sure that a certain mobile would play 3GP, but look at your possibilities:

1) It supports 3GP: You're done.

2) It supports another format: 
  a) Do many users access from that mobile? no > don't care about it
  b) Yes? then try supporting it too.

3) It actually supports flash, or even AVC: support it if it's worth the hassle, since they must also support 3GP

4) They don't support video: Just tell that to the user!

:)